# backbone - event not fired on selected element changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm generating a drop down list from `Backbone.View`.
After attaching it to the DOM, change event is not fired. The `delegateEvents` doesn't fixes it. Can somebody show me where the blind spot is?

Model and collection:

```
App.Models.DictionaryItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
        default: {
            key: '',
            value: '', id: 0
        }
    });

    App.Collections.Dictionary = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: App.Models.DictionaryItem,
        initialize: function (models, options) {

        },
        parse: function (data) {
            _.each(data, function (item) {
             //   if(item){
                var m = new App.Models.DictionaryItem({ key: item.code, value: item.name });
                this.add(m);
           // }
            }, this);
        }
    });
```

Views:

```
App.Views.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'option',
        attributes: function () {
            return {
                value: this.model.get('key')
            }
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this.template = _.template(this.model.get('value'));
        },
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template());
            return this;
        }
    });

    App.Views.CollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'select',
        attributes: {
            'class': 'rangesList'
        },
        events: {
            'change .rangesList': 'onRangeChanged'
        },
        initialize: function (coll) {
            this.collection = coll;
        },
        render: function () {
            _.each(this.collection.models, function (item) {
                this.$el.append(new App.Views.ItemView({ model: item }).render().el);
            }, this);
           // this.delegateEvents(this.events);
            return this;
        },
        selected: function () {
            return this.$el.val();
        },
        onRangeChanged: function () {
            alert('changed');
        }
    });
```

Rendering:

```
var coll = new App.Collections.Dictionary(someData, { parse: true });
var v= new App.Views.CollectionView(coll);
var vv=v.render().el;

//   new App.Views.CollectionView(coll).render().el;
$('body').append(vv)
```

Comment: `this.template = _.template(this.model.get('value'));` Judging by this line, it seems that you don't understand how JS templates work. Or do you really store JS template in a **model**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tagName` and `attributes` on `CollectionView`:

```
tagName: 'select',
attributes: {
    'class': 'rangesList'
},
```

say that the `el` will be `<select class="rangesList">`. But your `events`:

```
events: {
    'change .rangesList': 'onRangeChanged'
},
```

are listening to `'change'` events from a `.rangesList` *inside* the view's `el`. From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents):

> Events are written in the format `{"event selector": "callback"}`. [...] Omitting the selector causes the event to be bound to the view's root element (`this.el`).

So you're trying to listen for events from something that doesn't exist. If you want to listen for events directly from the view's `el` then leave out the selector:

```
events: {
    'change': 'onRangeChanged'
}
```